# How to get form POST input in Tornado?

Tags: python, forms, tornado

I amd new to Tornado framework and trying to make a simple form to upload images:

```
<form method="post" action="/uploads/{{uid}}/" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
    <input type="file" name="file1" /> <br />
  Image info: <input type="text" name="alt" /> <br />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" class="button" /> 
</form>
```

I can successfully receive the Posted file using:

```
if 'file1' in self.request.files:
            if self.request.files['imgfile'][0]: 
                    file1 = self.request.files['imgfile'][0]
```

However I'm unable to receive the `alt` input. I tried `alt = self.request.alt` but I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPServerRequest' object has no attribute 'alt'
```

and when I use  `alt = self.request.files['alt']`, I get:

```
  KeyError: 'alt'
```

I ran out of ideas so appreciate your help.

**UPDATE:**

I found that this works:

```
alt = self.get_argument('alt')
```

But still open for better solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try code below

```
self.get_body_argument("alt", default=None, strip=False)
```

Comment: This gives: `NameError: global name 'get_body_argument' is not defined
`

Comment: ok, Will you please elaborate what's the difference between `get_body_argument` and `get_argument`? Also what `strip=False` does?

Comment: get_body_argument returns from the body arguments which are post arguments and get_argument returns from both get/post arguments and strip=False means it does not strip whitespaces from end and start of argument

Comment: And if you are looking for another solution you can try self.request.body_arguments() which returns json as string so you need to  parse it to create dictionary and get the value you want but i think first way is better